Problem with gdal.warp reproject image while reducing resolution
I aim to reproject MODIS burned area (MCD64A1) data (Sinusoidal projection) to WGS84. In addition to reprojecting, I need to resample the origin bool image (burned or unburned) using mean algorithms to calculate the burned fraction in a coarser resolution (0.25 degrees). I was using gdal.warp to the origin file with below options:
kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff',
'dstSRS': 'EPSG:4326',
'resampleAlg': 'average',
'outputType': gdalconst.GDT_Float32,
'xRes': 0.25,
'yRes': 0.25}

ds = gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS=out_file, srcDSOrSrcDSTab=origin_ds, **kwargs)

I get the result with a decent burned fraction, but the location of each coarser pixel doesn't perfectly match the burned area.
This is just an example of the results, the red part is the bool image, and the coarser pixel is my burned fraction result. It has a left-right shadow in places classified as not burned and omits parts of the origin burned area.

What I previously thought the gdal.warp would do when you reproject the map while aggregating pixels:
Is gdal.warp firstly reproject the origin map to WGS84 coordinate and then create a grid in 0.25 resolution, and do statistics within the grid like the figure below:

What I found so far:
Because when I load the MCD64A1 product in QGIS, the software can't recognise the CRS (shows unknown CRS), and when I add the 'srcSRS': 'ESRI:54008',(this is world sinusoidal projection, I thought it's very similar to MODIS Sinusoidal) to the warpOptions. The result gets more displaced with the bool map than what I leave srsSRS as empty. Next, I want to try other reproject functions in rioxarray to see if this package makes it more sensible.
The file is available: link
code used:
def monthly_BF_resample_TP(self):
    infdir = "/Volumes/My Passport/Fire/Burned Area/MCD64A1/transformed/Merged_TP"
    outdir = "/Volumes/My Passport/Fire/Burned Area/MCD64A1/transformed/monthly_Burned_Fraction_TP"
    template_fname = "/Volumes/My Passport/Fire/Burned Area/MCD64A1/transformed/Merged_TP/2010/001.tif"
    temp_file = "temp.tif"
    T().mkdir(outdir)
    for year in tqdm(T().listdir(infdir)):
        fdir = os.path.join(infdir, year)
        for i, fl in enumerate(T().listdir(fdir)):
            fname = os.path.join(fdir, fl)
            imagei = rasterio.open(fname)
            arr = imagei.read(1)
            arr[arr < 0] = 0
            arr[arr >0] = 1
            out_file = os.path.join(outdir, str(year) + '-' + "{:0>2d}".format(i+1) + '.tif')
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(out_file), exist_ok=True)
            dataset = gdal.Open(template_fname, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
            band1 = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
            rows = dataset.RasterXSize
            cols = dataset.RasterYSize
            ds_new = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(temp_file, rows, cols, dataset.RasterCount,
                                                          band1.DataType)
            ds_new.SetGeoTransform(dataset.GetGeoTransform())
            ds_new.SetProjection(dataset.GetProjection())
            ds_new.WriteArray(arr)
            kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff',
                      # 'srcSRS': '',
                      'dstSRS': 'EPSG:4326',
                      'resampleAlg': 'average',
                      'outputType': gdalconst.GDT_Float32,
                      'xRes': 0.25,
                      'yRes': 0.25}
            ds = gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS=out_file, srcDSOrSrcDSTab=ds_new, **kwargs)
            del ds_new


I think you are right, but the average is computed before warping from the "contributing pixels", from the source pixels which are consumed for creating the target pixel https://gdal.org/en/stable/programs/gdalwarp.html. Your agree that the result looks strange.

You wrote "origin bool image" but the image statistics show that the nodata is -2 and data range is between -1 and 213. Do you know how the data is encoded?

Thank you for the immediate response. Ohh, that's why! But do you know other function in python that will reproject map before computing average. I want these processes (reproject and aggregate) done within one simple function.

Original image means the date of burn. I firstly preprocess the image with the code i provided in the question. That will transfer it to bool image. -2 is the nodata which is water body, -1 means no observation.

I found a workaround but I cannot thoroughly explain what happens. I believe it has to do with warping from sinusoidal into EPSG:4326, that requires whole lot of warping and therefore GDAL takes the source pixels "contrubuting pixels" from a wider area than a user can guess. The average is computed from the source pixels.
The workaround is to warp the image first into EPSG:4326 with the default nearest neighbor resampling.
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 183.tif 183a.tif

The output can be a virtual raster https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/raster/vrt.html. Creating a VRT file is very fast and the image data does not need to be copied so it can be recommended as interim format.
Now resample the interim image (tiff or VRT) into bigger pixel size with average resampling.
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 183.tif 183a.vrt
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 -r average -tr 0.25 0.25 183a.vrt 183b.tif



Thank you, but this workaround makes the whole process extremely slow, when it comes to process a large tiff (first reproject to wgs84).

It seems to work as well by using a GDAL VRT file in between and it takes no time at all.
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 183.tif 183a.vrt .

I'll try that, thank you
